# BlackBerry: setting column width and row height for GridFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this problem, because it actually works when the `GridFieldManager` is instantiated in the constructor of the `MainScreen`. If I load it after my json callback, or choose another month to load the gridfield again, I get the columns and rows being larger that I had set it.

```java
theCalendar = new GridFieldManager(rows,7,GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE);

int column_width = Display.getWidth() / 7;

for(int y=0;y<7;y++){               
   theCalendar.setColumnProperty(y, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, column_width);
   System.out.println("column width:"+theCalendar.getColumnWidth(y));               
}

for(int o=0;o<rows;o++){
   theCalendar.setRowProperty(o, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, 40);          
}
```

Like I said, if I fire this code in something other than the constructor, the rows and columns are larger than what I had set it as. I even checked `getColumnWidth()` and it comes up as **68**, which is right ( **480 / 7** ). Is there something wrong with my labelfields that I'm adding to it? I feel like it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the width of columns. I could solve it using `GridFieldManager.PREFERRED_SIZE_WITH_MAXIMUM` instead of `GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE`.